# How to fix this logical error about listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, conditional-statements

I'd like to create a list box in vb.net that lists the item whenever the user clicks the button it updates information, my variables are a string and an integer concatenated, the problem is that when the user clicks on the button the item doesn't remove on the list

I've tried converting the integer variable to string and it still doesn't work

```
Private Sub btnAddChicken_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddChicken.Click
        If cmbChicken.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
'''qfried is the quantity
'''tfried is the total amount
'''tfried and qfried are the variable i want to update
            qfried = qfried + 1
            tfried = tfried + pfried
            If ListAllOrders.Items.Contains("Fried Chicken - P" & Convert.ToString(tfried) & " Quantity (" & Convert.ToString(qfried) & ")") Then
                ListAllOrders.Items.Remove("Fried Chicken - P" & Convert.ToString(tfried) & " Quantity (" & Convert.ToString(qfried) & ")")
                ListAllOrders.Items.Add("Fried Chicken - P" & tfried & " Quantity - (" & qfried & ")")
                i += 1
            Else
                ListAllOrders.Items.Add("Fried Chicken - P" & tfried & " Quantity - (" & qfried & ")")
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

I expect that the information would be updated

Answer (score 1):

The remove option of the ListBox does not work with Strings, but with ListBoxItems. For you to remove it, you can do it like this:

```
For Each item In ListAllOrders.Items
     If item.Contains(desiredStringToRemove) Then 
          ListAllOrders.Items.Remove(item)
          Exit for 
     End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response, anyway i solved my problem by playing around the code, i figured out that the placing of remove and add is not in the right place so that is why the item in the listbox does not remove and updated with the new info